# How to insert custom row with dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

The title could have been something else. I am fairly new to Powerbi and I am trying to build a dynamic income statement. The data is imported from sql tables. I have tables for journal entries and chart of account. I dont know how to implement gross profit row (which comes after revenue, COGS before the expenses) and Net Income (after expenses)in the statement.

I managed to create it as a calculated table initially but I soon discovered slicers dont work on calculated tables. can someone point me in the right direction? Is there a way to use slicers on calculated tables or can I somehow do this with the matrix or table visual?

For those not familiar with the jargon

Journal entries table

| Account id | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xxxx |
| 2 | xxxx |
| 3 | xxxx |

COA table

| id | Name | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sales | Revenue |
| 2 | Cost of Sales | COGS |
| 3 | General Expenses | Expense |

Expected Income statement visual

| Type | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| Revenue | xxxx |
| COGS | xxxx |
| **Gross Profit** | **xxx** |
| Expense | xxxx |
| **Net Income** | **xxxx** |

Gross profit = Revenue - COGS

Net income = Gross profit - Total expense

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create measures:**

```
Balance Measure = SUM('Journal entries table'[Balance])

Revenue Measure = CALCULATE([Balance Measure],'COA table'[Type]="Revenue")

COGS Measure = CALCULATE([Balance Measure],'COA table'[Type]="COGS")

Expense Measure = CALCULATE([Balance Measure],'COA table'[Type]="Expense")

Gross profit = [Revenue Measure]-[COGS Measure]

Net income = [Gross profit]-[Expense Measure]
```

**2. Create new table:**

Table Measure:

```
Table = DATATABLE("Type",STRING,
 {{"Revenue"},{"COGS"},{"Gross Profit"},{"Expense"},{"Net Income"}})
```

Add Column:

```
Balance = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    [Type]="Revenue",[Revenue Measure],
    [Type]="COGS",[COGS Measure],
    [Type]="Gross Profit",[Gross profit],
    [Type]="Expense",[Expense Measure],
    [Type]="Net Income",[Net income])
```

[image]